# Special journal types with biblatex-chicago

Tags: citing, biblatex-chicago

I have two situations in which I can't figure out the right combination of fields for journal entries.

In the first case, the journal number is simply the year, even though it is actually published 4 times a year in specific months. Entries are identified by an integer which begins with 1 and runs over the course of the year (entry "nabu" in the MWE). A typical first citation tends to look like "J.S.N. Auteur, 'Le long titre', *Nouvelles assyriologiques brèves et utilitaires* 2000/75" (or "... NABU 2000/75"). I'm not married to this exact format (trying to do CMS after all), but I've not been able to come up with a combination which is elegant and doesn't reduplicate the year. Leaving the date field out gets me close but leaves a spurious comma in the citation.

The second, more common case, is when a journal number is split into fascicles; the item may span one or more fascicles. The reference should read something like "16 1/2" or "16 (1/2)" or the like. I can do this by specifying `number = {{16 1/2}}` but number is supposed to be an integer not a string....

I've fiddled with `volume`/`number` (sort of works but doesn't look like all the other journal citations), `issue`, `eid`, `part` (apparently only for volumes and in any case not a range)....

(I should mention that for that matter, sometimes the journal number is a range as well.)

I'm wondering what my best approach to these situations might be.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage{filecontents}
    \begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{nabu,
Author = {J. S. N. Auteur},
%   Eid = {?},
langid = {french},
Journaltitle = {Nouvelles assyriologiques brèves et utilitaires},
Location = {Paris},
Publisher = {Librairie Machin-chouette},
volume = {2000},
number = {75},
Shorttitle = {titre},
Title = {Le long titre}}

@article{Ebeling:Amerika,
Author = {Erich Ebeling},
Isbn = {3-535-01365-8},
langid = {german},
number = {16}, % fascicle  1/2,
Pagetotal = {153},
journaltitle = {Mitteilungen der altorientalischen Gesellschaft},
Title = {Altbabylonische Briefe amerikanischer Sammulungen aus Larsa},
location={Osnabrück},
publisher={O. Zeller Verlag},
date={1972},
origlocation={Leipzig},
origpublisher={Verlag von Otto Harrassowitz},
origdate = {1943},
Note = {reprinted with permission}}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[style=british,english=british]{csquotes}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
    \setdefaultlanguage[variant=british]{english}
\usepackage[%
    backend=biber,
    language=british
    ]{biblatex-chicago}
    \addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\mainmatter
First citation.\footcite{nabu}

Second citation.\footcite{Ebeling:Amerika}

\backmatter
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: `issue` is intended for things like double issues e.g. `issue = {1/2}`, according to Biblatex's manual. Here, you wouldn't specify `number` at all. For the `75` case, I would put `volume = 75` and put the year in `date`. Or is 75 really a number-within-year i.e. they'll start again at '1' next January?

Comment: The second might be better typeset as a book. After all, journals do not have ISBNs, so if it really has an ISBN, it isn't a journal. But, again, some books are better typeset as journals. When items don't match a paradigmatic type, sometimes you need to make them into a type which isn't initially the obvious choice. For example, do you need the publisher information here? If so, you probably need to treat it as a book; if not, more likely as a journal.

Comment: For your first problem I would just go with `date = {2000}, volume = {2000}, eid = {75}, number = {3},` and would bite the bullet of the year appearing twice (suppose for some reason that the 2000 volume was delayed and only published in 2001, then you'd want both fields, right?). For the 1/2 you can again try to use `eid`.

Comment: The `Ebeling:Amerika` entry seems to be a weird mixture of `@article` and `@book` (in a series). Pictures of other articles in that series show the article title on the title page, which would make it more like a `@book` (for an `@article` the journal title would be given on the title page). And the papers in this series are often quite long. But then there are apparently sometimes two or three articles that are published bound together in one volume, that looks more `@article`-like. If you cite the reprint and that is clearly a `@book` (with an ISBN) you might as well go for `@article`.

Comment: @cfr The NABU item numbers within a year do indeed restart with the first issue of each year. For Ebeling, yes, a curious hybrid. I had it set up as a book initially... but it's "Mitteilungen" so a kind of proceedings....

Comment: @moewe Many of the works in my field defy clean categorization. I guess at the end of the day, my main problem is how to specify ranges in fields which are expected to be simple integers.... Hmmm. I'll fiddle some more given the suggestions made here.

Comment: Can't test at the moment, but with *most* fields that are supposed to be integers it should be possible to also give non-integer input. You might get a backend warning and depending on the field format (I'm thinking about `edition` here) the automatic bibstring might be suppressed, other than that you'll be fine. For nice output you'd input `number = {1\bibrangedash 2}`.

Comment: @moewe That's more or less what I had before (except for `\bibrangedash`), I was just concerned about nasty effects from non-kosher usages. I'll look at this again tomorrow (I also cannot test just now).

Comment: Made changes as suggested, all seems to work fine. Should I post what I did as a solution or how do we close out?

Comment: Just post a self-answer and accept it if you are happy with your solution. It might help other people after all.

Comment: Ok, thanks. It turns out there's a little hitch to putting things beyond integers in the `number` field which merits mention. Everyone's help appreciated as always!

Answer (score 1):

In these particular cases, the key, as suggested in the comments, is to be slightly less rigorous in one's understanding of the discrete categories.

The MWE below showcases four notes and bibliography pairs. In the first, the "NABU" situation has been resolved by amplifying the `volume` field with the issue or "sub-volume" (even though ordinarily an integer is called for) while also amplifying the `date` with the month of issue. In this manner, the desired information is provided without giving the appearance of complete duplication of the year only.

In the second case, the ambiguous book/article was reverted back to "book within series" while the `number` field was amplified with the fascicles covered, again despite an integer being called for. This had no undue side-effects. (NB: as noted in the comments, this might be problematic for fields such as `editor` where a computation is performed based on the data given.)

The third and fourth cases show the attempt to apply the same principle to a journal article, which is potentially a *little* more tricky. In the third example, the `number` field was amplified as before, but note how, in the output, the preceding literal has become "nos." rather than "no." since the software detected the presence of "additional things". Depending upon one's understanding, this may or may not be acceptable (does a journal number with multiple fascicles constitute a plurality, or does the prefix apply to the journal number only, in which case, "nos." is incorrect?). The fourth instance shows how to remedy this problem if desired.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
    @article{nabu,
        author = {J. S. N. Auteur},
        langid = {french},
        journaltitle = {Nouvelles assyriologiques brèves et utilitaires},
        location = {Paris},
        publisher = {Librairie Machin-chouette},
        volume={2000-2}, % second issue of the year
        number={75},
        pages = {11--99},
        title = {Le long titre},
        shorttitle={Titre},
        date = {2000-06}} % issue published in June
    @book{Ebeling:Amerika,
        author = {Erich Ebeling}, 
        isbn = {3-535-01365-8},
        langid = {german},
        number = {16 1\bibrangedash2}, % no. 16, fascicles  1 and 2,
        pagetotal = {153},
        series = {Mitteilungen der altorientalischen Gesellschaft},
        title = {Altbabylonische Briefe amerikanischer Sammulungen aus Larsa},
        location={Osnabrück},
        publisher={O. Zeller Verlag},
        date={1972},
        origlocation={Leipzig},
        origpublisher={Verlag von Otto Harrassowitz},
        origdate = {1943},
        note = {reprinted with permission}}
    @article{Arnaud:catalogue,
        journaltitle = {Syria},
        author = {Daniel Arnaud},
        journalsubtitle = {Revue d’art oriental et d’archéologie},
        location = {Paris},
        number = {48  3\bibrangedash4},
        pages = {289--293},
        publisher = {l’Institut français d’archéologie de Beyrouth},
        title = {Catalogue des textes trouvés au cours des fouilles et des explorations régulières de la mission française à Tell Senkereh--Larsa en 1969 et 1970},
        url = {http://www.jstor.org/stable/4197739},
        urldate = {2018-01-31T19:33:00},
        date = {1971}}
    @article{Arnaud:catalogue1,
        journaltitle = {Syria},
        author = {Daniel Árnaud}, % change last name to coerce full entry
        journalsubtitle = {Revue d’art oriental et d’archéologie},
        location = {Paris},
        number = {{48  3\bibrangedash4}}, % extra braces = 1 unit
        pages = {289--293},
        publisher = {l’Institut français d’archéologie de Beyrouth},
        title = {Catalogue des textes trouvés au cours des fouilles et des explorations régulières de la mission française à Tell Senkereh--Larsa en 1969 et 1970},
        url = {http://www.jstor.org/stable/4197739},
        urldate = {2018-01-31T19:33:00},
        date = {1971}}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[style=british,english=british]{csquotes}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage[variant=british]{english}
\usepackage[%
    backend=biber,
    language=british
    ]{biblatex-chicago}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\mainmatter
First citation.\footcite{nabu}
Second citation.\footcite{Ebeling:Amerika}
Third citation.\footcite{Arnaud:catalogue}
Third citation, modified.\footcite{Arnaud:catalogue1}
\backmatter
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Snapshot of footnotes:

[image: snapshot of footnotes]

Snapshot of bibliography:

[image: snapshot of bibliography]